# Pandas minute-data find- first local min between now and first occurrence of (threshold) condition

Tags: python, pandas, transform

Looking to find the first occurrence
from current time for each row until the end of the date
where the value passes some threshold

```
thresh = 0.10
```

creating dataframe columns for the min inside that window

Input

```
timestamp           date       value endofdaytime  
2018-03-11 13:03:00 2018-03-11 0.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52  
2018-03-11 13:08:00 2018-03-11 0.00 2018-03-11 16:29:52  
2018-03-11 15:22:00 2018-03-11 0.11 2018-03-11 16:29:52  
2018-03-11 16:03:00 2018-03-11 0.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52  
2018-03-11 16:29:52 2018-03-11 0.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52  
2018-03-12 13:03:00 2018-03-12 0.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59  
2018-03-12 13:08:00 2018-03-12 0.00 2018-03-12 16:29:59  
2018-03-12 16:03:00 2018-03-12 0.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59  
2018-03-12 16:29:59 2018-03-12 0.12 2018-03-12 16:29:59
```

output

```
timestamp           date      value endofdaytime        min2thresh thresh
2018-03-11 12:34:00 2018-03-11 0.22 2018-03-11 16:29:52 0.00       0.11
2018-03-11 13:03:00 2018-03-11 0.00 2018-03-11 16:29:52 0.00       0.11
2018-03-11 13:08:00 2018-03-11 0.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52 0.03       0.11
2018-03-11 15:22:00 2018-03-11 0.11 2018-03-11 16:29:52 0.04       0.12
2018-03-11 16:03:00 2018-03-11 0.04 2018-03-11 16:29:52 0.12       0.12
2018-03-11 16:29:52 2018-03-11 0.12 2018-03-11 16:29:52 NaN        NaN
2018-03-12 13:03:00 2018-03-12 0.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59 0.00       0.13
2018-03-12 13:08:00 2018-03-12 0.00 2018-03-12 16:29:59 0.00       0.13
2018-03-12 16:03:00 2018-03-12 0.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59 0.03       0.13
2018-03-12 16:29:59 2018-03-12 0.13 2018-03-12 16:29:59 NaN        NaN
```

This code will get me the min until the end of the date.

```
df['min2thresh'] = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cummin()[::-1])
```

But  only want the min until the threshold is passed.
    So I assume I need to change the -1 in

```
[::-1]
```

to a method to find the first location of that threshold.  Perhaps..

```
[:: df.loc[(df["value"] >= thresh)]]
```

So that would be

```
df['min2thresh'] = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform(lambda x: x[::df.loc[(df["value"] >= thresh)]].cummin()[::df.loc[(df["value"] >= thresh)]])
```

But that crashes with "cannot do slice indexing on ... with these indexers.."